# How to take armpit odor from jacket

Tags: cleaning, clothing, smell

I get very quick armpit odor and tried nivea body odor but it doesn’t well, now I was being lazy and put on new jacket on my to be washed shirt but too late and the odor is in jacket which transferred into my new clothes. Which is super annoying as those r fresh clothes and jacket is new. 
How can I deodorize  my jacket from odor 
[image: label]

Comment: Have you laundered the jacket?

Comment: No, it hasn't been one month of the jacket and I am afraid of destroying it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one way to get rid of the odour, and luckily, your jacket is washable; there's no real hack for this, because trying to disguise the odour by spraying with something won't do the trick, it will still smell, just mixed in with whatever perfume is in what you try to cover it with. Wash it in the machine at 30 or 40 degrees using biological washing liquid or powder. Getting the odour out would likely be more successful if you spray or apply Vanish liquid under the arms of the jacket on the inside first. The wash label pictured suggests there's some sort of trim on the jacket which needs removing prior to washing, so don't forget to do that. The label also indicates the jacket can be tumble dried, but only on a low temperature, see washing label guide here https://www.supersavvyme.co.uk/home/laundry/understanding-labels

Comment: I am afraid of destroying the jacket as it is not even a month old jacket and might lose its shine and warmness. The only trim I see is the fur on the hood.

Comment: It has a wash label - there should be no problem at all with washing it and the garment should be intact at the end of the process - if its not, you can return it to where you bought it from as faulty. Perhaps the fur trim is removable - I've got a jacket with hood where the fur trim invisibly buttons on to the fabric of the hood which I unbutton and remove prior to washing. I note the label also talks about 'brushing' to restore the pile - not sure what that refers to because I can't see the fabric of the garment, but if you don't wash it, you've just got an almost new smelly jacket.